# Idiomatic way to handle datastructures packed inside a map?

Tags: clojure

Lets assume we have a data structure that describes a moving ball.

```
(def moving-ball {:position [100 100]
                  :velocity [1 3]
                  :acceleration [0 0]})
```

Is it idiomatic to write an update-fn that destructures the map, updates the properties and returns a new map? Like that:

```
(defn update-acceleration
  [{:keys [position] :as s} mx my]
   (let 
     [[x y] position
     dx (- mx x)
     dy (- my y)
     dir (normalize [dx dy])]
      (assoc s :acceleration dir)))
```

Or is it better to seperate the functions?

```
(defn direction
 [[x y] mx my]
 (let [dx (- mx x)
       dy (- my y)]
  (normalize [dx dy])))


(defn update-map
 [{:keys [position] :as s} mx my]
 (assoc s :acceleration (direction position mx my)))
```

The first is coupled to the data structure (and thus not really reusable) but the second requires more code. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I haven't been using Clojure long enough that my opinion would count, but to me this looks the kind of thing that's a matter of personal preference and other context.  The difference in the amount of code is small.  Given other similar functions, what's going to be fastest to read and understand a year from now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we improve the way that the data is presented to the functions, we can usefully extract function `direction` from entanglement with the map data structure. This is related to what the refactoring folks call [introduce (or extract) parameter object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) and [extract method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

The problem is the uneven way that [x y] co-ordinates are presented: sometimes as two numbers, sometimes as one pair. If we represent all of them as pairs, we can get a better grip on what the functions are doing.

If we do this to the `direction` function, it becomes ...

```
(defn direction [[x y] [mx my]]
 (let [dx (- mx x)
       dy (- my y)]
  (normalize [dx dy])))
```

... which we can reduce to ...

```
(defn direction [from to] (normalize (mapv - to from)))
```

Now we have a function that we can understand at sight. As it's likely to find use outwith `update-acceleration` as well as within it, it's viable. (The same function with meaningless argument names was not so convincing).

In the same spirit, we can reform `update-acceleration`:

```
(defn update-acceleration [{:keys [position] :as s} [mx my]]
   (let 
     [[x y] position
     dx (- mx x)
     dy (- my y)
     dir (normalize [dx dy])]
      (assoc s :acceleration dir)))
```

... which reduces to ...

```
(defn update-acceleration [s m]
    (assoc s :acceleration (normalize (mapv - m (:position s)))))
```

... or, employing the `direction` function, ...

```
(defn update-acceleration [s m]
  (assoc s :acceleration (direction (:position s) m)))
```

You would get some benefit from so refactoring in any language. Clojure's sequence library amplifies the effect. (Other sequence libraries are available: any Lisp or other functional language, Smalltalk, C#, ... YMMV)

---

P.S.

I am guessing that `normalize` returns a unit vector in the same direction. Here's one way to do it using the sequence functions:

```
(defn normalize [v]
  (let [length (->> v
                  (map #(* % %))
                  (reduce +)
                  Math/sqrt)]
    (mapv #(/ % length) v)))
```

This is definitely worth extracting. In fact, I'd be tempted to pull out `length`:

```
(defn length [v]
  (->> v
       (map #(* % %))
       (reduce +)
       Math/sqrt))
```

... and define `normalize` as ...

```
(defn normalize [v]
  (let [l (length v)] (mapv #(/ % l) v)))
```

A wee warning: `mapv` will stop silently on its shortest argument, so you might want to check that all its arguments are the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic would be to use `update-in`. See http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in

`update-in` would then use the function you called direction. The Function update-in takes the old value of moving-ball and apsses it as an argument to the update-function. So you would have to change direction accordingly.

Comment: This isn't super-helpful, because he needs the information in the rest of the map (not under the `acceleration` key) in order to know how to change `acceleration`. `update-in` is great for isolated changes, but doesn't give you that information.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you want to use `update-in` in the given `update-map`, you have to do something like this:
`(update-in s [:acceleration] (fn [_] (direction position mx my))))`